# How to get last part of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
"application/controllers/backend"
```

I want get:

```
backend
```

of course the `backend` it's dynamic, so could be change, so I'm looking for a solution that allow me to get only the last part of the string. How I can do that?

Comment: [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop)`(`[`explode`](http://php.net/explode)`('/', $str));`?

Comment: `basename("application/controllers/backend")`

Comment: @Andrew LOL that is very clever solution.

Comment: @felipsmartins thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thing like this :

```
echo end(explode("/", $url));
```

If this thorws error then do :

```
$parts = explode("/", $url);

    echo end($parts);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take the advantage of `basename()` to get the last part

in your case, it will be

```
basename("application/controllers/backend");
```

Output:

```
backend
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = explode ("/", $string);
//$arr[2] is your third element in the string
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
basename("application/controllers/backend");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 0):

You did ask initially for a solution with regex, so, although the other answers haven't involved regex, here is one approach which does.

You can use `preg_match` and `str_replace` for this:

```
$string = '"application/controllers/backend"';

preg_match('/[^\/]+"/', $string, $matches);

$last_item = str_replace('"','',$matches[0]);
```

`$last_item` is now a string containing the word `backend`.

Comment: Too complex for this use case though.

Answer (score 0):

And, if you want to do it with a regex:

```
$result = (preg_match('%.*[/\\\\](.*?)$%', $url, $regs)) ? $regs[1] : '';
```